# Happy New Year 2022!

Tags: discussion

Happy New Year to all!

On this one day of the year as we struggle with so many issues as diverse Christian communities, both as communities and on a personal level, I wish to ask God’s blessings on all of each and every one of you.

Covid-19 has not been easy to deal with. I pray that it will go away and never come back!

My home area has been hit  in 2021 with record heat waves in June, record floodes in November and severe snow storms in December. Many families have lost everything. May Our Lord see in his infinite mercy to assist all those who are struggling at the beginning of the Year 2022, both here and around the globe.

Happy New Year to all and may we continue to pray as Christians for all of mankind.

PS. You all remain dear to my heart, whether or not you share my personal perspectives on Christianity.

Please be assured that I will continue to pray for all on this community. Pax!